# Can you loop a range of data in a time series?

Tags: vba, charts

Does anyone know how to loop "ranges"?

I have monthly time series data that spans over 100 years. Only the X and Y variables. And I'd like to create a chart for each of the years. Here's the simple code for creating one of the charts...

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3:B14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (4)
    ActiveChart.Legend.Delete
    Dim a As Range
      Dim b As ChartObject
      Set a = ActiveSheet.Range("D3:J19")
      Set b = ActiveChart.Parent
      b.Height = a.Height 
      b.Width = a.Width   
      b.Top = a.Top       
      b.Left = a.Left
```

The problem is that this is only for one of the years, and it wouldn't make sense to recreate this code 100 times over.

I hope I've delineated the problem here clearly, if anybody has a solution to loop this process, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your data is in order in column A.

What I would do, is use a range object to represent the upper left corner of your range, and use offsets from there.  I have also cleanup your use of select and active*, which can be very error prone
.
    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim a As Range
    Dim b As ChartObject

```
Set wksht = ActiveSheet
Set cell = wksht.Range("A3")

Do While (Not IsEmpty(cell))
    cell.Resize(12, 2).Select
    Set cht = wksht.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    With cht
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .ApplyLayout (4)
        .Legend.Delete
    End With
    Set a = cell.Offset(0, 3).Resize(17, 7)
    Set b = cht.Parent
    b.Height = a.Height
    b.Width = a.Width
    b.Top = a.Top
    b.Left = a.Left
    Set cell = cell.Offset(12, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Worked out perfectly!